# Why does opencv normalize a grayscale image into a matrix full of zeros?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to feed an image to a LibTorch Tensor. For this I do some preprocessing first in opencv. An important part is normalization. I use the cv::normalize() method for this but the printed Mat object is full of zeros.

I found some Code and tried it but it did not help. Here it is:

```
Mat m = imread("image.jpg",0);
Mat_<float> fm;

m.convertTo(fm,CV_32F);
```

The Code i actually use is as follows:

```
Mat image_to_tensor(string filename, int flag) {

    Mat image = imread(filename, flag);
    Mat_<float> out;
    float hight = image.rows;
    float width = image.cols;
    Size size(128,128);
    imshow("Not Resized", image);

    resize(image, image, size);
    image.convertTo(out, 5);
    normalize(image, image, 0.5, 0.5);
    imshow("Resized IMG", image);
    cout << image;
    waitKey(0);

    cout << "left image to tensor" << endl;
    return image;
}
```

I expected a Mat object, which contains numbers between zero and one. I got a Mat object full of zeros.

Comment: Are you sure it's reading in from the filepath correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If I comment this part `image.convertTo(out, 5);
    normalize(image, image, 0.5, 0.5);` the code works. But the range of the numbers is too high.